# how to change a letter in a string

Tags: python

I received the following multiple choice question in a task

Which is the answer from the code bellow?

A. COLD

B. CORD

C. TypeError: ’str’ object does not support item assignment

D. ”

```
str1 = "COLD"
    for letter in str1:
        if letter == "L":
            letter == "R"


print(str1)
```

I don't understand why it could be A (COLD)
why wouldn't it be B (CORD) or the c (type error)

Comment: that doesn't answer the questions I have after the code, could you explain why B and C are wrong

Comment: Do you see anything assigned back to original string `str1`. Only you set `letter = 'R'` (why double equals?)

Comment: Idk, this was just a multiple choice question on an exam. I'm just trying to figure out why the answer is the right answer. Thanks for the help tho, I think I understand it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate through `str1`, `letter` is actually just a copy of every character in `str1`. Think of it as the difference between passing by value instead of passing by reference in a language such as C++.

When you modify `letter`, you are not actually modifying the underlying string, `str1`. `letter` and the corresponding character in `str1` are not linked. (Not to mention that strings are immutable anyway.)

Also, side note, the question is using `==` instead of `=`, so you actually aren't changing anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is COLD because the program as written will not change str1 at all. In fact, the program is unworkable in three ways:

1) In python, strings are immutable. You cannot change them once they've been assigned a value. You'd have to make an entirely different string and build its value by looping over each character in str1, making the conditional letter assignment as part of that process. You cannot change str1 directly.

2) The program as shown violates the indentation rules of python--"for letter in str1:" should not be indented and python will throw an "IndentationError: unexpected indent" when you try to run it. Did you try to run it?

3) "if letter == "L":" is the same as saying, "if letter *is* "L" but "letter == "R" means nothing at all in this context. When you use a "==" you are testing for a value, not assigning a value. In order to assign a value, you would use "=" (a single equals sign).

It's a good exam question because unless you really know a few things about python, it *looks* like the program ought to do something. Maybe you couldn't try the code before you answered the exam question, but by all means try things out using the python REPL. It gives you instant feedback. Cheers!